# Are there any security implications when embedding a username/password in an rss feed URL?

Tags: security, rss, fogbugz

I noticed that when I added the FogBugz RSS Feed to my iGoogle page I had to embed my username and password in the feed URL. So are there any security risks associated with doing this?

EDIT:
Yes, my question should have specifically stated https and whether or not the query string portion of the url is encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not a HTTPS url then yes.

If not it doesn't mean your account has been compromised yet but you're sending authentication information over an unencrypted channel... you're asking for it.

If it is HTTPS you're fine. HTTPS urls *are* encrypted.

Comment: So if HTTPS encrypts the url it must just encrypt the query string portion?

Comment: HTTPS establishes the connection SSL before transmitting anything about the URL. The only information that is exposed is the server address it is connecting to.

Comment: @FUD: Yeah the protocol stack goes something like IP->TCP->SSL->HTTP. So really, aside from the fact that the standard HTTPS port is 443 they can't even know for sure what protocol you're using.

Comment: OK, so it cannot be intercepted, but could the data be logged in plaintext serverlogs on the receiving HTTPS server, and quite possibly also in browser history. How about the url being available to browser plugins and possibly even other applications on the client computer?

Comment: You can't know for sure. Whether or not there are logs for HTTPS url depends on the server and whether or not your browser logs the information depends on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Sensitive information within URLs may be logged in various locations, including the user's browser, the web server, and any forward or reverse proxy servers between the two endpoints. URLs may also be displayed on-screen, bookmarked or emailed around by users. They may be disclosed to third parties via the Referer header when any off-site links are followed. Placing session tokens into the URL increases the risk that they will be captured by an attacker.